# Xamarin white screen bug in QR Scanner

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I open the application it works perfect. But when I use my scan button again it's stuck on a white screen and not passing until I press the "Back" Button on my phone.
How can I remove that white screen bug?

Video about my bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8-haOmCzm0

QR Code Scanner Code:

```cs
public async void Scan()
{    
    var scan = new ZXingScannerPage();
    await Navigation.PushAsync(scan);
    scan.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
        {
             Navigation.PopAsync();
             codes.Text = result.Text;

             Application.Current.Properties["codes"] = codes.Text;
             Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        });
    };
}
```

My Scan again button Code:

```cs
private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new ScanPage());
}
```

Comment: don't create a new instance of ScanPage for every scan

Comment: @Jason  how can i do it ? When i delete "new" and make my code like 
 private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(ScanPage());
        }

Its not working. How Can i do it ?

Comment: Keep a class level reference to the page

Comment: @Jason I'm newbie idk how can i keep a class level reference too. I'm Sorry. I searching it but if u have link or what about that can u give me ? So i can learn it.

Comment: you need to give a better explanation of the pages involved and the navigation flow between them.  Which page contains the "Scan" function?  And which page contains "Button_Clicked_1"?

Answer (score 0):

From shared code, you have pushed twice to the scan page, however you only use one time `PopAsync` after get result.

But also used the third push in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`：

```
 Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

You could modiy this line with following code to check whether it works.

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
 {
     Navigation.PopAsync();
     codes.Text = result.Text;

     Application.Current.Properties["codes"] = codes.Text;
     Navigation.PopAsync();
 });
```

============================**Update**================================

If you scan code when lauching application, when receiving results, you could use `Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();` to back to Root Page of Applicatuon.

Code as follows:

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
 {
     Navigation.PopAsync();
     codes.Text = result.Text;

     Application.Current.Properties["codes"] = codes.Text;
     Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
 });
```

Comment: When i change my button code as Navigation.PopAsync(); Its just stay in white screen again. did i something wrong ? My programm starting in ScanPage so i cant change first one with PopAsync coz its first page. So i changed Button but like i said its giving same white screen

Comment: Hi, not changing your button code. I mean the code inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: @UğurcanUçar I have updated the answer, you could have a check that.

Comment: Hi, i tried it but like i said it my first page. When i open my app its starting with scanner. So when i use PopAsync to scan page in first scan its not sending me to my mainpage.

Comment: Jiang -MSFT By the way thank you for trying to helping me! But unfortunetly it didnt work coz scanner is starting page :/

Comment: @UğurcanUçar Okey, if so, you could use `Application.Current.MainPage =new MainPage()` to check.

Comment: @UğurcanUçar Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @Jian -MSFT I know you are mad me brother but im newbie and my english is kinda bad. I trying my best. But now i didnt get where should i write Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage(); it. I literally tried everywhere. i wrote it to my button to scanpage everywhere but cant found it. Can you help me ? if you being mad me i can give you my teamviewer id too for it will be easier to teach me.

Comment: @UğurcanUçar Oh, sorry, the updated answer has wrong. I have updated it again. And you only need to modiy that line code inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to check. Good luck!

Comment: @Jian -MSFT I did it its same brother. Its staying in white screen again :(

Comment: @UğurcanUçar You could share the sample project link, I will check that in local site.